# Selenium wait interface

Tags: selenium

I have difficulty in understanding the following method in the Selenium wait interface. Can somebody please explain me the below construct

```
<T> T until(com.google.common.base.Function<? super F,T> isTrue)
```

I can't follow what Function and super F,T denotes above

Regards
Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

Basically Selenium will wait until the provided Function returns true. You can either use the provided [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) or create your own.

For ExpectedConditions, a simple example is

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // creates a new 10s wait
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Home")); // waits (10s, defined above) until the title of the page is "Home"
```

You can find more info here, 
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits

For creating your own, a simple example is below but you can google and find lots more.

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.findElement(...).getText().length() != 0;
        }
    });
```